# Adding variable to Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script which return variable from website  "$_.id -eq "s215".

I wish i could add a variavble to it and return both

I tried below function but I got an error that variable $form can not be found ....

I found this solution at microsoft site - > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6 example 5

Can you please help

```
Function MyFunctionTemp{
    clear-host
        $Uri = "http://....../index.asp" 
        $Form = @{
        Name  = 'John'
                 }
        $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -FOrm $Form
        $Result.AllElements | Where {$_.id -eq "s215"} | Select Name, innerText | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $headPath
}
     $html_url = MyFunctionTemp
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html_url) | Out-File  "\\plwawprn01\xpbuild$\IT\Level0\scresult\test.htm"
```

Btw the HTML piece looks like this

[image]

Error Below

[image]

Comment: What PowerShell version do you have? Run `$PSVersionTable` to check this

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` will be returning... or at least attempting to return JSON as an object. What does `$Result` look like? Perhaps you mean to be using `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: The error is complaining about the parameter `-Form`, not the variable `$Form`. This is because you are using the cmdlet `Invoke-RestMethod`, not `Invoke-Webrequest` which is the one used in the link - don't know enough about web requests to tell if it's as simple as making that change.

Comment: I have the same error using Invoke-Webrequest as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not that `$Form` cannot be found. The error says that `Invoke-RestMethod` have no idea what parameter `-Form` is.

Make sure to run `$PSVersionTable` and look at `PSVersion` property on its output and then choose the correct version via dropdown on documentation website:

[image: Choosing PS version on the documentation]

Also, as mentioned in the comments (credits to [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) and [@gms0ulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039142/gms0ulman) for noticing that) you might want to try using `Invoke-WebRequest` instead.

Comment: Youi are right ... i have ver 5 , the question is is it still possible to do it at this ver ?

Comment: I think you can try to use `-Body` for that

Comment: That might be something application-specific, please refer to the documentation of the app. If you can reproduce the same request in browser, you can use Chrome Dev Tools to translate your request to PowerShell ([post about this](https://foxdeploy.com/2018/04/02/faster-web-cmdlet-design-with-chrome-65/)).